# Reinterpret a Fortran array as bytes

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I would like to interpret a Fortran (`real*8`, say) array as an array of bytes, so that it can be sent to a function to process things on the byte level. What's a simple (preferably no-copy) way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not clear what is a function working on byte level. Does it use Fortran characters? Or 1-byte integers? They are different beasts in Fortran.

You could try to lie about the signature of your function and just pass the array as it is. Likely to work, not strictly standard conforming.

`Transfer()` is the best modern tool for similar purposes, but it may indeed involve temporaries.

If the size of the array is fixed (it is not allocatable or pointer or dummy argument) you could use `equivalence` which is quite similar to `union` in C.

But you must be careful about what is allowed, this is a notoriously dodgy area. Even the C union rules differ from the C++ rules. Fortran equivalence has its own rules and more strict, I am afraid. Type punning is not allowed, but a lot of code in the wild does it.

Doing tricks with C pointers and pointing to the same array from different pointers with different types is definitely not standard conforming and may give you expected results in some cases and wrong results in others (undefined behaviour as they call it in C and C++).

Comment: It uses Fortran characters.

Comment: MAP and UNION also work, which are dec extensions, but I do not understand what working on a fortran Character would look like.  A BYTE or an INTEGER*1 I understand.... Or a CHARACTER and uppercase it.

Answer (score 1):

A "NO_COPY" way...but relies on DEC extensions:

```
USE ISO_C_BINDING
IMPLICIT NONE
UNION
  MAP
    REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE)    , DIMENSION(N)   :: R8_Data 
  END  MAP
  MAP
    BTYE                   , DIMENSION(N*8) :: B_Data 
  END  MAP
  MAP
    CHARACTER(LEN=1)       , DIMENSION(N*8) :: C_Data 
  END  MAP
  MAP
    INTEGER(KIND=C_Int16_T), DIMENSION(N*4) :: I2_Data 
  END  MAP
  MAP
    INTEGER(KIND=C_Int32_T), DIMENSION(N*2) :: I4_Data 
  END  MAP
END UNION
```

@Valdimir equivalence also works if one does not have access to the DEC extensions.

There is a slated upgrade to gfortran to add in the MAP and UNION DEC extensions, so in time it will be there too.

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56226

My appreciation of the difference is back on track...
One can use UNION/MAP inside of a structure. Outside a structure/TYPE then EQUIVALENCE does all one needs.

So As Vladimir mentioned this also is a "no copy"...

```
REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE)    , DIMENSION(N)   :: R8_Data 
BTYE                   , DIMENSION(N*8) :: B_Data 
CHARACTER(LEN=1)       , DIMENSION(N*8) :: C_Data 
INTEGER(KIND=C_Int16_T), DIMENSION(N*4) :: I2_Data 
INTEGER(KIND=C_Int32_T), DIMENSION(N*2) :: I4_Data 

EQUIVALENCE(R8_Data, I4_Data)
```

It is almost more dangerous than it is worth, unless one has a specific problem.

Comment: The question is, whether it is allowed to use this union for type punning. It is not allowed in C++, for example.

Comment: it works, but any byte math would corrupt the doubles. I do not know why the OP would want to do it. I have >1M lines of source supplied to me that has this and would take it all out if it was not a monumental task.

Comment: Works and is guaranteed to work by the specification are two different things. A simple test may be misleading and a problem can come very unexpectedly as in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30475 or https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71892 GCC is especially known for using undefined behaviour for optimizations but Intel might do similar stuff, although I expect them to be more conservative.

Comment: I have no idea why someone would operate on the doubles as bytes. Using UNION/MAP with ifort works, and for a flexible buffer using a pointer it is not uncommon. There is a lot of similarity with equivalence which I am failing to appreciate. I do not particularly like the idea of working a double as 8 bytes.